Exception while reading from stream
While running Add-Migration command I am getting following error :
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
 ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|54_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageLong(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean async, CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean async, CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteScalar(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Migrations.Internal.NpgsqlMigrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

This is how my database context class looks like :
public sealed class ArchivesDbContext(DbContextOptions<ArchivesDbContext> options) 
    : DbContext(options), IUnitOfWork
{
    internal DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Schemas.Archives);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SubjectConfiguration());
    }
}

I have tried adding Keepalive = 1 and CommandTimeOut = 60 but still I am getting same error.
I am using Postgres SQL from Supabase

What happens in the migration? Maybe it's just to much for the timeout you allow.

I don't see any problem with your code. Maybe there is some external factor causing the timeout error. The issues I can think of right now are from following:
1. Poor network connection.

Solution: Try to increase your Command Timeout. May be 120 or more.

2. Busy Supabase server.

Solution: Try to migrate your database to your local system and check
if it works.


The connection string parameters are case-insensitive and the the other points are very generic, non-specific suggestions, not pointing at the root cause. Basically, we can't diagnose this error.

@GertArnold Thanks for acknowledging that the connection strings are case-insensitive. I didn't think of that when I answered. Other than that I tried to help the user with the most possible scenarios based on the details provided in question.

Yeah, but those are of the type "is the battery charged"?
